# Get up-to-date facebook crawler ip list

Tags: c#, facebook, whois, cidr

i hope some one can help me. I need to know if a ip request is from facebook. 
I have a small list of ip range in cidr format and i'm able to know it the current request ip is in this range. BUT the ranges i have are out dated and i wish to be able to update it frequently

Facebook say [on the doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler#access):

> whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route

**But how i can** :

1) Get this list on my windows machine. (To update my list manually)

2) Get this list from my c# code. (To update my list automatically)

an other question for what i need :
[List of IP Space used by Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164672/list-of-ip-space-used-by-facebook)

**The error i get in cmd on windows:**

> C:\Users\Benoit>whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934'
>
> Whois v1.12 - Domain information lookup utility
>   Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
>   Copyright (C) 2005-2014 Mark Russinovich
>
> Usage: whois [-v] domainname [whois.server]¸
>
> -v   Print whois information for referrals

Comment: Well, that is  Linux/Unix command you have as an example. "grep" isn't on Windows (normally), so even if whois works you're going to have problems with that example anyway. but doesn;t the error message say how to do it? It says to use "whois -v facebook.com whois.radb.net" I believe. Right?

Comment: As i understand, i'm supposed to get info from AS32934. Im able to do a whois to facebook.com but i dont get the ip ranges ...

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. I don't run Windows, so I can't test this problem. Sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is use https://whoisclient.codeplex.com/ and use the following code.

```
using Whois.NET;
...
var result = WhoisClient..Query("-i origin AS32934", "whois.radb.net");

Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", result.AddressRange.Begin, result.AddressRange.End);
```

That should get you going in the right direction. You could parse the results and use them how you see fit.

Comment: Also try WhoisClient..Query("!gAS32934", "whois.radb.net");